# Connecting external SAP database to MySQL

Tags: sql, database, architecture, sap

My application relies on **data that is stored in a SAP Database**. In addition to that, I need to persist data that **references** the SAP data but cannot be stored in the SAP database. So there is **another** (MySQL) database.

**What would be the cleanest way to connect those 2 datasources?**

I think it would be better/safer to constantly get the data I need from SAP and also store it in the MySQL database, since I can reference them with FKs. But I do not want to always check for changes in the SAP database and then copy all the data to MySQL since queries to SAP are usually very expensive.

Comment: Does sap by now have a clean data api? Because if not and you go with copying data from (oracle) sap db into your own db you will run into problems with the dreaded upgrades.

Comment: we plan to implement an API to access the SAP data

Comment: what are the users (and the number of them) of this application you try to build on mysql? Consumers or people used to sap's slugginess?

Comment: the app is for businesses that already use SAP. it will be built on top of the sap system to cut off some complexity. It should scale well since it will (hopefully) be used by a large number of employees. Therefore, performance and consistency are big factors

Comment: I'd at least consider implementing it within SAP if possible. Usually topics like backup and restore, authorization and authentication, data storage and the likes are already sufficiently answered for a SAP system. You can use the data dictionary, SAP ERP has tools to implement translations and your users work in a familiar environment. Depending on the data you need you might also have a chance to use IDOCs to get new and changed documents into your external application. But that is only possible for some of the documents created within SAP (e.g. sales and purchase orders, invoices).

Comment: I need for examples skills that are assigned to employees. do you think that an sap database can represent that @DirkTrilsbeek? I'm not an SAP expert..

Comment: The question is more if you have SAP experts at hand to develop that for you. The SAP ERP system can do almost everything other solutions can do, but you need the appropriate knowhow. If you need to develop it yourself, don't have the knowledge and don't have the time or budget to get proper training you may have to develop your application outside the SAP system. SAP has a few add-on solutions for its HR module, maybe buying instead of developing is also a possibility for you. It is usually ridiculously expensive if you need something small and simple, but that is more up to you to decide.

Comment: I'd say: if your extra data is relatively small (eg. 1~5 tables) just do it in sap and make a .net or java api interface on top of that that you use in your app. If you are going to try to directly copy/modify sap's data in their database you are entering a world of pain. But, you do need a abap/java/net sap programmer to do that for you since this is a very specific skill set (SE11 anyone?), with not to many programmers available.

Comment: SAP is a software company. Many of these software store content in database, whatever it's SAP RDBMS (HANA, etc.) or not SAP (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, etc.) That would be minimum information to know before being able to answer anything.